# Pointer to Reference Is Illegal

Tags: c++, templates, reference, c++14, pass-by-reference

I've been getting into template metaprogramming as of late, only to realize just how difficult template debugging can be. Case in point I am receiving a "pointer to reference is illegal" error when I try to compile the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

//Empty Entity Class
class Entity {
};

#define COMPONENTS X(Entity)
#define COMPONENTSLIST X(Entity)
#define X(ARG) std::vector<ARG>
using ComponentTuple = std::tuple<COMPONENTSLIST>;
#undef X


//EntityManager stuff
class EntityManager {
    static ComponentTuple components;
public:
    template<class T>
    static auto& Components();

    template<class T>
    static void AddComponent(Entity&, T&&);
};

template<class T>
auto& EntityManager::Components()
{
    return std::get<std::vector<T>>(components);
}

template<class T>
void EntityManager::AddComponent(Entity& e, T&& c) {
    auto& comp = Components<T>();;
    comp.push_back(c);
}

#define X(ARG) std::vector<ARG>
std::tuple<COMPONENTSLIST> EntityManager::components;
#undef X


//ContentManager Stuff
class ContentManager {
    bool LoadComponent(std::string data, Entity& entity);

    template <class T>
    static void LoadComponent(std::string data, Entity& entity);
};

template <class T>
void ContentManager::LoadComponent(std::string data, Entity& entity) {
    T component{};
    EntityManager::AddComponent(entity, component);
}

bool ContentManager::LoadComponent(std::string data, Entity& entity) {
    LoadComponent<Entity>(data, entity);
}
```

The cause of the error is the line `EntityManager::AddComponent(entity, component);` in the `LoadComponent` (which was not easy to figure out considering the error points to `xmemory`).

The problem I am having is that I never requested a pointer, as far as I can see, so this error seems quite strange to me.

At this point any help would be greatly appreciated (pertaining to the error or even tips for future template debugging). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vexing parse for `T component();`(function declatation), use `T component{};` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 Whats the difference? Doesn't it equate to the same thing, or is it just a standard? Isn't it calling the constructor which is a function?

Comment: As said: `T component()` declares a function named `component` with no argument and returning a `T`, while `T component{}` creates an object of type `T` named `component`.

Comment: `T component();` is a function declaration: function named `component` returning `T` and taking no argument. `T component{};` define `component` as default construct `T`.

Comment: @Ryoku did you search for "Vexing parse"?  You'll find an entire wiki page that can describe it better than a comment here

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay I see it now. Thanks for the clarification. I hadn't heard of the term vexing parse before (didn't think to look it up because I just thought you were telling me it was vexing). Unfortunately it doesn't seem like ambiguity was the problem. I made the correction but the error persists

Comment: `auto& comp = Components<T>();` is problematic: reference or temporary variable. Notice also that `Components<T>()` would be `Components<U&>()` in your case (as `T&&` come from l-value) you probably want `std::decay_t<T>` instead.

Comment: I see you took the time to create a minimal example (although at first glance it looks it can be made even minimal, but that is just nitpicking from my part). Good job. It would be even better if you would put it all together in just one file so we can just copy/paste and compile :),

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks for the tip, I'm looking into `std::decay_t<T>` and trying to wrap my head around it. From what I can gather, using `std::decay_t<T>::type` will give me the type referred to by T, is this correct?

Comment: @Ryoku: First, it is `typename std::decay<T>::type` or `std::decay_t<T>`. then basically, `std::decay_t<T&>` is `T`.

Comment: @Jarod42 so if `std::decay <T&>` is `T` then what is `std::decay <T>`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I figured it out, so decay just "takes a step back" so in my case since my parameter is `T&&`, then `std::decay_t<T>` is `T&`. Other words it goes from being an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference. At least that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: `std::decay_t<T>` is an alias for `std::decay<T>::type`. `std::decay<T>` is a structure with an alias named `type`.

Comment: In your case, with `T&&` you have `T` == `U&` (and also `T&&` == `U`). so `std::decay_t<T>` is `std::decay_t<U&>` and so `U`.

Comment: @Jarod42 What do you mean when you say `T == U&`? What is `U` and why does the class I give the template equate to an lvalue reference? Sorry about all the questions I tried researching the answer but I was unable to find anything relevant

Comment: `ContentManager::LoadComponent<T>(..)` calls `EntityManager::AddComponent<T&>(entity, component);`. As both methods are template, speaking of `T` for both seems ambiguous (even if in code, it is completely ok to use same for both).

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax of `AddComponent` to:

```
static void AddComponent(Entity&, T);
```

or

```
static void AddComponent(Entity&, const T&);
```

and your code compiles, at least with gcc. So this has not necessarily something to do with your templates, but with the way `push_back` handles rvalue references.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the reason is though, maybe someone with more knowledge of the STL can enlighten us.